# "Until" times out but condition met on first iteration - Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an Until that keeps looping until it times out.  I thought I had a good understanding of how to build it but I must be getting something wrong.

I start by initializing a variable:

[image]

Then I have my Until set up.  It is to loop until the variable = 'TRUE'

[image]

My next step is a 'Compose' action. Because I have had the step fail but then succeed when I resubmit the action, so I thought I should include a delay before a second iteration plus a notification.

The delay and the notification only run if the 'Set variable' is skipped.

[image]

But as you can see here, it keeps looping until it times out at 60 runs and all of them set the variable to true.

**Why is it not stopping after the first successful iteration?**

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

Comment: What was the error that you are getting and also what is inside the compose action?

Comment: Are you sure your variable shouldn’t be a Boolean, not a String?

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda There is no error, it just loops through the 60 iterations with each one succeeding.  The Compose is successful which leads to setting the variable to TRUE. At that point it should stop and exit the loop but it doesn't.  It just keeps looping until it times out.  Every loop is successful and sets the variable to TRUE.  The loop is looking for TRUE in the variable and should then stop looping, but it keeps going. The compose is just a simple substring expression to isolate a string from an incoming email.

Comment: @Skin  I did try Boolean but have not been able to make it work.  I need to dig deeper into Boolean variables to better understand how to make them work but even as a String variable, if the strings match, it should stop, right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the type of the `Type Success` that you are trying to compare. Make sure you change `True` to `string(True)`. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks to SwethaKandikonda and @Skin, I now understand what I was doing wrong.  Using True/False as values complicates functioning because the system does not always interpret them as a string.  If I had used any other word or string, it would have worked fine.